# How to store XML format data in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, mongodb

I have several files in XML format. Each file contains XML header and approx 15-20 items. I want to store these files in MongoDB which I think stores data in JSON format. Here is the sample of data I want to store in MongoDB.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Channel Title</title>
        <link>Channel link</link>
        <description>Channel desc</description>
        <!-- Item 1 -->
        <item>
          <title>Your Title</title>
                    <link>Your link</link>
          <pubDate>Published date</pubDate>
          <description>Your description</description>
        </item>
        <!-- Item 2 -->
        <item>
          <title>Your Title</title>
                    <link>Your link</link>
          <pubDate>Published date</pubDate>
          <description>Your description</description>
        </item>

    </channel>
</rss>
```

How to proceed? Can anyone help using some example and sample code how to store these data in MongoDB? **Note: I will be using Node/Javascript for CRUD operations.**

**Edit:** 
The process of storing data would be like there is a form and you choose a category(Channel name, like channel title) and you just add a `<item>` to that channel. But whole data would be stored in MongoDB.

Comment: that make scene to you.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Is there any confusion in understanding the question? Let me add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

There is no xml type in mongodb. Every thing is BSON in mongodb internally.

You can save as string form.

```
    var str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
    <rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"\
        xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" version="2.0">\
        <channel>\
            <title>Channel Title</title>\
            <link>Channel link</link>\
            <description>Channel desc</description>\
            <!-- Item 1 -->\
            <item>\
              <title>Your Title</title>\
                        <link>Your link</link>\
              <pubDate>Published date</pubDate>\
              <description>Your description</description>\
            </item>\
            <!-- Item 2 -->\
            <item>\
              <title>Your Title</title>\
                        <link>Your link</link>\
              <pubDate>Published date</pubDate>\
              <description>Your description</description>\
            </item>\
    \
        </channel>\
    </rss>'
  console.log(str);
```

This is string. Now you can save it in mongodb.

If data is coming from outside is in some string or any other type, the only approach is convert to string and then fetch it when you wanted. You will get the same xml string back you wanted.

Comment: Actually, I want to push each item according to channel name and store in MongoDB. Like if there are two channel `DSA` and `CN' then I want to push an item in the respective category. For example, for two channel, there will be two XML file and in each XML file I want to add item according to their channel name. Also, can you provide me some link on how to do CRUD operation in MongoDB and javascript?

Comment: What you are asking that is xml parsing ? For CRUD operation , you can check out http://mongoosejs.com/docs/ in node.js . or can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb . i use mongoose . For mongodb guide there is no best guide other then its offical site .